# Derby: 2nd Trigger for same event causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, derby, triggers

I trying to resemble an Oracle schema in a Derby database for testing purposes.
The schema should also include 2 triggers for the same table.

I defined them as follows:

```
create trigger myTrigger
    after update on myTable
    referencing old as oldRow new as newRow
    for each row MODE DB2SQL
        delete from otherTable where otherTable.id=newRow.id and newRow.usable is not null and newRow.usable='1' and oldRow.usable='0';

create trigger myTrigger2
    after update on myTable
    referencing old as oldRow new as newRow
    for each row MODE DB2SQL
        update myTable set counter=0 where myTable.id=newRow.id and newRow.usable is not null and newRow.usable='1' and oldRow.usable='0';
```

When I define only one of them, it's working fine, but as soon as I define both at once, I get this error:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: '-1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at de.bmw.database.DerbySqlConnector.sql(DerbySqlConnector.java:287)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: '-1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager.popContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextImpl.popMe(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.destroy(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.dictionary.SPSDescriptor.getPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.dictionary.SPSDescriptor.getPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.GenericTriggerExecutor.executeSPS(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RowTriggerExecutor.fireTrigger(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.TriggerEventActivator.notifyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.UpdateResultSet.fireAfterTriggers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.UpdateResultSet.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with the trigger definitions?

Comment: Trigger problems are often hard to reproduce. Can you reproduce this one easily in a standalone simple example? If you can, I encourage you to get in touch with the derby-dev mailing list at Apache and report it to the developers, since this certainly looks like a Derby bug to me.

Comment: Interesting. I found the time to create an isolated example and the triggers work properly within this simpler setup. It seems like the problem is related to remaining schema setup.
I will update this posting as soon as I found the source of evil.

Comment: To follow up the issue: I isolated the problem and found out that it actually works standalone. But if our whole schema is applied, it causes above errors.
Unfortunately I don't find the time to further analyze the problem, since we decided to switch to h2 anyways soon.